# How to access Owner Role via Formula in Contact object?

Tags: workflow, formula, workflowrule

I'm creating a Workflow that will set a field with the record owner's role during creation.

However, when I try to add the formula (**Owner:User.UserRole.Name**)
I instead get this error: Error: You don't need to specify an object type for the Owner field. Remove User from your formula.

I'm really confused as how to access the Role name for the Owner and I'd really much appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `Owner.UserRole.Name` in place of `Owner:User.UserRole.Name`.

Comment: @jerarddelavictoria N.B. `Owner:User.xxx` notation is used when the Owner is polymorphic to `Queue` and `User`. This can't happen for `Contact`.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, your solution works and thanks also cropredy for explaining that. Now I know why the previous formula didn't work. Again thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @cropredy, just a thought, Contact cannot be assigned to a queue, example of standard object which can be assigned to queue: Lead, Case, Order, Knowledge Article Version